# How to access a parent's current state from function passed to child

Tags: reactjs

Currently working on a Form with a FileUploader Component nested inside.

I would like users to remove files in the FileUploader child-component, but also need the Files (blobs) data to be accessible in the Form parent-component.

I passed down my state and removeFile callback to the child component. The issue I am facing is when `removeFile()` is called from the child-component, it does not reference current files. Instead, the previous state of files before the child-component is mounted.

```
function Form() {
   const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

   removeFile(key) {
      console.log(files);    // ISSUE: Returns previous state of files when the FileUpload is mounted.
      var updated_files = files.removeFileByKey(key);     
      setFiles(updated_files);       
   }

   return () {
     <div>
            // Other Form Inputs
            <FileUploader files={files} setFiles={setFiles} removeFile={props.removeFile}/>
     </div>
  }
}

function FileUploader() {
    onFileAdd(more_files) {
         props.setFiles(more_files);
    }

    return (
        props.files.map(file => {<File onClick={props.removeFile(file.key)} />)
    )
}
```

**How can I access the current reference to files from a function prop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**One work around** this is to store the files in both parent and child components and create a function to synchronize in the child child component.

```
function Form() {
   const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

   return () {
     <div>
            // Other Form Inputs
            <FileUploader files={files} setFiles={setFiles} />
     </div>
  }
}

function FileUploader() {

    const [filesCopy, setFilesCopy] = useState([]);
    
    syncFiles() {
         props.setFiles(filesCopy);
    }    

    onFileAdd(more_files) {
         setFilesCopy(more_files);
         syncFiles();         
    }
    
    removeFiles(key) {
      console.log(filesCopy); // This will return current state of files
      var updated_files = files.removeFileByKey(key);     
      syncFiles();
    }

    return (
        filesCopy.map(file => {<File onClick={removeFile(file.key)} />)
    )
}
```

!! However, this solution is bad since it requires storing files TWICE. This will be heavy on memory.